# Issue Oppening files to write to in intro C++

Tags: c++, writetofile

I'm working on a program right now and am getting this error:

```
writeOddEven.cpp:35: error: no match for call to ‘(std::ofstream) (const char*, const std::ios_base::openmode&)’
```

which I've never seen before and can't seem to find any information about online. In my program I'm trying to read-in user specified names for 2 files, then input user-specified integers to the files based on them being even or odd. My code so far is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
  string odd_name;    //odd number file name
  string even_name;   //even number file name
  ofstream fout_odd;        //fout for odd file
  ofstream fout_even;       //fout for even file


  //Get file names
  cout<<"Enter name of file for odd integers: ";
  getline(cin, odd_name);
  cout<<"Enter name of file for even intgers: ";
  getline(cin, even_name); 

  //Open files;
  fout_odd(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out);             //*ERROR HERE*
  fout_even(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);           //*ERROR HERE*

...

fout_odd.close();
fout_even.close();
```

the only thing I can think of is some sort of error with my format for "ios::out", but I have no idea how to rephrase that.

**EDIT** So I completely forgot about the "open()" part on these lines:

```
  fout_odd(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out);
  fout_even(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);
```

So they should read:
      fout_odd.open(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out);
      fout_even.open(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);

Comment: Constructors go where the object is created.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 //^^^^remove these two lines
 ofstream fout_odd;        //fout for odd file
 ofstream fout_even;       //fout for even file


  //Get file names
  cout<<"Enter name of file for odd integers: ";
  getline(cin, odd_name);
  cout<<"Enter name of file for even intgers: ";
  getline(cin, even_name); 

 //Open files;
 //^^you should supply parameters when constructing 
 //the fout_odd and fout_even object
 ofstream  fout_odd(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out); 
 ofstream fout_even(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);
```

You may find more information from [C++ File I/O documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

**EDIT**: you may also try the following:

```
 ofstream fout_odd;        //fout for odd file
 ofstream fout_even;       //fout for even file


  //Get file names
  cout<<"Enter name of file for odd integers: ";
  getline(cin, odd_name);
  cout<<"Enter name of file for even intgers: ";
  getline(cin, even_name); 

 //Open files; provide option when open the files to write
 fout_odd.open(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out); 
 fout_even.open(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);
```

Comment: He can keep the lines at the top, but call the open() function supplying the parameters later. Either option should work.

Comment: @VictorSand yes, I agree.  That's another option. Will add into the post,thanks!

Comment: Using that I got an error about "redeclaration of 'std::ofstream fout_odd'", but I ended up trying something similar. I commented out the top "ofstreams" and kept the rest of your code and it seems to work now. 

Thanks!

Comment: @user2250690 you may need to remember that you have to remove the first two lines I pointed out when you use the above first way. good to know that it works.

Comment: @tacp I forgot to edit those out haha, they're for later on in the program.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to open file

either open it with the constructor

```
ofstream fout_odd( odd_name.c_str() );
```

or invoke it after with open

```
fout_odd.open( odd_name.c_str() );
```

there is no need to pass `ios::out` since it is the default for ofstream

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
//Open files;
fout_odd(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out);             //*ERROR HERE*
fout_even(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);           //*ERROR HERE*
```

with

```
//Open files;
fout_odd = ofstream(odd_name.c_str(), ios::out);             
fout_even = ofstream(even_name.c_str(), ios::out);
```